# There are two format of Time series datetime in the same series, how to change them to one format?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, datetime, timestamp, time-series

I want to split a time series into two set: train and test.
Here's my code:

```
train = data.iloc[:1100]
test = data.iloc[1101:]
```

Here's what the time series looks like：
[image]

And here's the train series：There's no time, only the date in the index.

[image]

Finally, the test:
[image]

How to change the index to same form?

Comment: Hmmm, I think if same dataframe separated by iloc, there are only no `00:00:00` show. So add times is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the simplified series `s`

```
s = pd.Series(1, pd.date_range('2010-08-16', periods=5, freq='12H'))

s

2010-08-16 00:00:00    1
2010-08-16 12:00:00    1
2010-08-17 00:00:00    1
2010-08-17 12:00:00    1
2010-08-18 00:00:00    1
Freq: 12H, dtype: int64
```

But when I subset `s` leaving only `Timestamp`s that need no time element, `pandas` does me the "favor" of not displaying a bunch of zeros for no reason.

```
s.iloc[::2]

2010-08-16    1
2010-08-17    1
2010-08-18    1
Freq: 24H, dtype: int64
```

But rest assured, the values are the same:

```
s.iloc[::2].index[0] == s.index[0]

True
```

And have the same dtype and precision

```
print(s.iloc[::2].index.values.dtype)

dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

And

```
print(s.index.values.dtype)

dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if same dataframe separated by `iloc`, there are only no 00:00:00 show. So add times is not necessary, because both `dtypes` are [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html).

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['GOOG'],
pd.DatetimeIndex(['2010-08-16 00:00:00',
                  '2010-08-17 00:00:00',
                  '2010-08-18 00:00:00',
                  '2010-08-19 00:00:00',
                  '2010-08-20 15:00:00'])], names=('Ticker','Date')) 

data = pd.Series(range(5), mux)
print (data)
Ticker  Date               
GOOG    2010-08-16 00:00:00    0
        2010-08-17 00:00:00    1
        2010-08-18 00:00:00    2
        2010-08-19 00:00:00    3
        2010-08-20 15:00:00    4
```

---

```
#splitting
train = data.iloc[:2]
test = data.iloc[2:]
print (train)
Ticker  Date      
GOOG    2010-08-16    0
        2010-08-17    1
dtype: int32
```

It seems there are some times as mentioned [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared):

```
print (test)
Ticker  Date               
GOOG    2010-08-18 00:00:00    2
        2010-08-19 00:00:00    3
        2010-08-20 15:00:00    4
dtype: int32

#check if same dtypes
print (train.index.get_level_values('Date').dtype)
datetime64[ns]

print (test.index.get_level_values('Date').dtype)
datetime64[ns]

#if want see only times in test dataframes
m = test.index.get_level_values('Date').time != pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01').time()
only_times = test[m]
print (only_times)
Ticker  Date               
GOOG    2010-08-20 15:00:00    4
dtype: int32
```